# Преобразование объектов в примитивы возвращает, неправильный результат

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  name: ' Опа',
  age: 100,
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint == "string") {
      // Выводит {name:Опа}.
      return `{name:${this.name}}`;
    } else {
      // Результат должен быть {age:100} аналогично {name:Опа},
      return `{age:${this.age}}`;
    } // но выходит ошибка. Как решить эту проблему?

  }
};

alert(user);
alert(+user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator) оператор `унарный +` выполняет следующие действия:

1. Вычисляет значение параметра
2. Вызывает внутреннюю функцию `ToNumber` и возвращает ее результат.

---

Согласно [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-tonumber) функция `ToNumber` выполняет следующие действия:

1. В случае примитивных типов возвращает результат согласно таблице
2. В случае объекта

   1. Приводит объект к примитивном значению с помощью внутренней функции `ToPrimitive`, передавая параметр `hint` равный `number`.
   2. Применяет себя же к полученному примитивному значению.

---

Применяя данный алгоритм к коду в вопросе можно заметить, что

1. для объекта определена его функция `ToPrimitive`,
2. для `hint=number` эта функция возвращает строку
3. согласно таблице, возвращенная строка не является числом
4. результат оператора - `NaN`

---

Чтобы получить `{age:100}` в данном случае, можно воспользоваться оператором `+`.

При сложении со строкой, примитивное значение второго операнда так же будет приведено к строке:

```js
let user = {
  name: ' Опа',
  age: 100,
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint == "string") {
      // Выводит {name:Опа}.
      return `{name:${this.name}}`;
    } else {
      // Результат должен быть {age:100} аналогично {name:Опа},
      return `{age:${this.age}}`;
    } // но выходит ошибка. Как решить эту проблему?

  }
};

console.log('' + user);
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно)

Comment: @Black_Viper, что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Каким методом заменить +, дабы был желаемый результат. Можно привести пример в виде кода, терминологию я прочту позже.

Comment: @Black_Viper, никаким. Ты не можешь напрямую получить значение `ToPrimitive` - эта функция используется только внутри других функций.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107737/discussion-between-grundy-and-black-viper).